# NTLM Authentication with JMeter is receiving a SocketException

Tags: apache, proxy, jmeter, ntlm

I'm trying to load test a SSO request with JMeter (version 2.13). I followed [this](https://blazemeter.com/blog/windows-authentication-apache-jmeter) tutorial and set up an HTTP Authorization Manager with Username, Password, Domain and Mechanism = BASIC_DIGEST.

When I set the proxy server settings of my HTTP Request to Server Name or IP = 127.0.0.1 and Port Number = 8888, I can see my request go through fiddler where it gets two 401 responses and then succeeds. This shows up in the JMeter View Results Tree as a single successful request. However, when I remove the proxy server settings, the request fails and I get the following response:

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:436)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:294)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.MeasuringConnectionManager$MeasuredConnection.open(MeasuringConnectionManager.java:107)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:643)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:479)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.executeRequest(HTTPHC4Impl.java:517)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:331)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1146)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1135)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:434)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:261)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The log viewer also says this:

```
org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl$6: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when connecting to the target host: Connection reset
```

I have been trying all sorts of things to get this working without the proxy settings including using the HttpClient4 implementation, setting the following in user.properties

```
hc.parameters.file=hc.parameters
```

and the following in httpclient.parameters

```
http.protocol.reject-relative-redirect$Boolean=true
```

I will also note that when I run the test through Fiddler, I get a prompt asking if I want to ignore remote certificate errors

```
Session #106: The remote server (server name here) presented a certificate that did not validate, due to RemoteCertificateChainErrors.
0 - Unknown error.
```

I am assuming this won't make any difference in JMeter as I [read](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#opt_ssl) that JMeter HTTP samplers are configured to accept all certificates.

Any help getting this up and running (without Fiddler) would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the Secure Credential Store I was trying to connect to required TLS version 1.0. I had to tell JMeter to use this by updating the jmeter.properties file with:

```
https.default.protocol=TLS
https.socket.protocols=TLSv1
```